# Why are markers not shown on PrimeFaces GMap?

Tags: primefaces

I use the following code to initialize a *MapModel* and add a test *Marker*.

```java
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
  advancedModel = new DefaultMapModel();
  advancedModel.addOverlay(new Marker(new LatLng(36.890257, 30.707417), "test"));
}
```

It is used as a *GMap* model with the following xhtml.

```xml
<p:gmap
  id="gmap"
  center="36.890257,30.707417"
  zoom="12"
  type="ROADMAP"
  model="#{mapBean.advancedModel}"
  style="width:100%; height:400px;"
/>
```

When I open the page in a browser the map shows up but it is not marked. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you add Getter/Setter methods for your model to your bean?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was on that I was using Spring framework.
The class had to be annotated with @Named instead of @ManagedBean